# Connecting iOS with external Mysql database without webservice

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, database, external

Does anybody know the method for the connection between Objective-C with an external database Mysql without a web service??
I've worked with Objective-C and Mysql database with Json but the last week a partner worked with Mysql and now my php files can't do the connection with the database.
I've looked for tutorials but I only found forums that told "Web service is the best way to work with this two tools". Please, Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great tutorial for implementing `SQLite` with `objective-c`. [SQLite tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/)

And you don't have to connect it to the web at all. The only reason you would connect it to the web is if you have 1 file that will be updated by users and all other users will have to see those updates.

But if it isn't going to be interactive, then all you have to do is drag and drop an `SQLite` file in. The tutorial will show you how to do everything.

Hope this helps!!

**Edit**

If you do need it to be interactive, and have web service integrated, then here is a great tutorial. [Integrating Parse in Objective-c](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-app-backend-parse/)

Comment: Thank you, but my database is an external database :(
I have to see the updates every 10 seconds

Comment: So in that case, there is no way of doing it without web service. You can check out something like parse. I'll update my answer with another link to a tutorial.